# MySQL sectioned ordering

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, mysql4

I have a data set like this:

```
boolean name    value
0       Text10  20
1       Text1   8
0       Text4   46
1       Text9   84
1       Text5   66
0       Text2   35
0       Text9   2
1       Text6   55
```

Ordering by the `boolean` column will split the data in two sections that I want to order according to a different parameter each: The ones with `boolean = 1` are ordered by value, and the rest are ordered by `name`, like this:

```
boolean name    value
1       Text1   8     # --> 1s are ordered by value
1       Text6   55
1       Text5   66
1       Text9   84
0       Text2   35    # --> 0s are ordered by name
0       Text4   46
0       Text9   2
0       Text10  20
```

Note: We need this to work in MySQL 4.1.11. =D

Comment: 4.1.11 OMG!  So sorry for you man....

Comment: Thanks @Ray, but I'm sorry enough. =p

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Notice that it can be done with multiple parts of `order by` that are 'activated' as needed.
You can check this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01fde/1)

```
select * from yourtable
order by 
  boolean desc, 
  case when boolean = 0 then value else null end, -- ´else null´ is redundant
  case when boolean = 1 then name  else null end  -- but is here to clarify
```

Comment: Took me some days to get back here, @bobwienholt. =D